# How to set products for campaign in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, categories, product

I would like to know how we can set certain products to campaign. The requirement is we will setup some campaigns and assign some products to those campaigns. The campaigns has some expiry date, and that will be set to disable automatically once the expiry date is reached.

The home page or some other page will lists the active campaigns and clicking on each campaign will list the associated products. Can i customize categories in order to acheive this, if so how to set expiry date for categories. I am newbee for magento. Some of your thoughts/idea greatly appreciated.

Note: i have to include the campaign related details in the report too.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: @Enigmativity then why there is 33k questions related to magento tag in stackoverflow. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/magento

Comment: Please don't try to argue that if someone else gets away with murder then murder must be legal for you. And it's certainly OK to ask on-topic questions that relate to Magento. What's on-topic is quite clearly laid out in [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the campaign activity by catalog price rule.

1) First of all decide which category product you want to include in campaign. By going to the Admin site Promotion -> catalog price rule
add a new price rule in rule information tab set the expiry date for the campaign.  [View here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rk2W9.png)

2) On the  conditions tab add the category which you want to set as campaign [View here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVbLF.png)

3) After this click on Save and Apply button

4) After then add this block to any where you want to list the products as per the category id update {{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" category_id="9" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}